# Reboot without having to decrypt LUKS partitions?

Tags: luks, kexec

Is there a way to `kexec` reboot a running kernel without having to decrypt an encrypted LUKS root filesystem?

I'd imagine not, but I'm not sure if there's a workaround for this.

Comment: You might be able to create a second initramfs with a embedded key file which is stored on the encrypted volume. This would at least solve the password prompt.
Just like the first answer now that i read it properly

Answer (score 2):

If my other answer does for some reason not meet your requirements (e.g. because you don't want a keyfile on your volume or your `/boot` is not encrypted), I can also recommend this project: https://github.com/flowztul/keyexec

Answer (score 0):

As grub2 supports decrypting LUKS-encrypted volumes, I'll assume that your `/boot` partition is encrypted as well. This also thwarts some evil-maid [attacks](https://twopointfouristan.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/pwning-past-whole-disk-encryption/).

If this is the case, you can safely have a key which can decrypt the volume inside your initramfs. Now, when kexec loads your initramfs into ram, it'll be able to decrypt your partition when loading the new kernel.

Because [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20170303093845/http://www.pavelkogan.com/2015/01/25/linux-mint-encryption/) to set up an luks keyfile inside of the initramfs, which also solves the problem of having to enter the keyphrase twice (first in grub, second when the initramfs is loading).